# Creating multiple test accounts

Tags: facebook, testing, user-accounts

As part of my work I need to test several flows between multiple accounts.
For that I would like to create multiple Facebook accounts and define specific relationships between them.

I would like to know if this is possible (even manually) in order to not abuse Facebook systems, and if so, then how.

Comment: Have you tried to google? Hint 1: "facebook api test account"

Comment: you will ue mailcatch account to create multiple facebook account